# Google Map not centering on users location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map on my site that gets the users location and then displays the map with the users location along with directions to a fixed point on the map. When the map loads it only fills a small corner of the div, I have got around this using the following code:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

However I now have the problem where the map is not zoomed into the specified level and it does not centre on the users location again as specified in the code.

Geo-location code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) { 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoInfo, noGeoInfo);
} else {
  noGeoInfo();
}

function geoInfo(position) { 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) { 
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                    
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                 
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); 
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = { 
      zoom: 15,        
      center: coords,
      mapTypeControl: true, 
      navigationControlOptions:
      {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL 
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(  document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions); 
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map); 
    var request = {
      origin: coords, 
      destination: '54.861283, -6.326805', 
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING 
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  });
}

function noGeoInfo() { 
  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(54.861283, -6.326805); 
  var mapOptions = { 
    center: location, 
    zoom: 15, 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Why is it not centering to the specified location or zoom level?

Comment: I thought the parameters where between 0-21 with 21 being the closest zoom (maximum)?

Comment: @AmitAgrawal adjusting zoom didn't make a difference.